# VBScript to delete a folder

Tags: vbscript

I'm using below code to delete the folder since it is used by other application I'm getting an error:

> Permission denied-Cannot delete a folder

I need a code to check if the folder is in use by other application, if so kill that process and then delete that folder.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\x")
'delete all files in root folder
For Each f In folder.Files
  On Error Resume Next
  name = f.Name
  f.Delete True
  If Err Then
    WScript.Echo "Error deleting:" & name & " - " & Err.Description
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Deleted:" & name
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
Next
'delete all subfolders and files
For Each f In folder.SubFolders
  On Error Resume Next
  name = f.Name
  f.Delete True
  If Err Then
    WScript.Echo "Error deleting:" & name & " - " & Err.Description
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Deleted:" & name
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
Next
```

Comment: What if the folder is blocked by explorer.exe? Killing this process might be risky.

Comment: Use [`openfiles` utility](https://ss64.com/nt/openfiles.html) with `/local on` option to [find out which process is locking a file](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-find-out-which-6012b2ac). Use [`taskkill` utility](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) to terminate that process.